# Open sets with addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $x_0 \in \mathbf{R}^d$ and $A \subset \mathbf{R}^d$. Prove that if $A$ is open, then

$x_0 + A=\{x_0 +x:x \in A\}$

is open, and if $A$ is closed then $x_0 +A$ is closed. What can you say about scalar multiples of open [closed] sets?

I believe I need to say something like: if $A$ is open, then every $x$ in $A$ is an open ball such that

$|x-a|<\epsilon \in A$, so $|(x+x_0)-(a+x_0)|<\epsilon\in x_0+A$, so $x_0+A$ is open.

and maybe since $|x-a|<\epsilon$ then for a constant $c$, $|cx-ca|<c\epsilon\in cA$

Is this going in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is correct.  A similar strategy will work when $A$ is closed-use the fact that $A$ is closed to argue that $x_0+A$ is also.  Your scalar multiple argument shows that the ball might have to be smaller in $A$ than in the multiple, but that is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that for fixed $a$ the function $F(x) = x + a$ is a homeomorphism. Then express the set $X + a$ as the preimage of an open set under a continuous map. Likewise for $G(x) = k \cdot x$ and the set $k \cdot X$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is right. If $A$ is any set containing the element $x$, where $x$ is a real number, and $x_o$ is any real number then
$A+x_o = \lbrace x_1+x_o, x_2+x_o, ..., x_n+x_o \rbrace$.
If $A$ is closed then $A+x_o$ is also closed.
The similar argument can be followed for scalar multiplication as well.